# Is there a way to configure git to use a different difftool based on the file extension?

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-difftool

I would like to setup git to launch different difftool executables ([DiffTool Man-page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)) based on the file extension.

This could be done with an external script or executable. For example, here is a posted Q&A with a shell script that could do this: [Git shell script for multiple difftools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083339/6501141), however, my team uses primarily Windows, and this is a Unix solution, and I'd prefer a built-in solution.

Is there a way of doing something similar by having different `[difftool]` or `[diff]` sections in my global `.gitconfig` and using something like the `.gitattributes` file?

I'm currently using the `.gitattributes` method to unzip a specific file extension, that is an archive, before git diff's it. Can this method be extended to also launch a different DiffTool based on a different `[difftool "mytool"]` section in the `.gitconfig`?

Or, is there some other way to do this that is built-in to git?

Comment: The short answer is "no", but since `git difftool` runs a script—the difftool helper script, which in turn can run whatever script you like—you could easily fancy these scripts up. Also, for general useful background, see [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58664365/1256452).

Comment: The example in the solution you linked was for Windows — have a look at the paths. What's wrong with using a script?

Comment: @alfunx Maybe nothing, but would prefer having my users configure git (which is a tool they already have installed) rather than install additional scripts/tools. It adds an additional dependency to a project/team.

Comment: If your users have to go through some process to have their tool configured according to the project/team needs, isn't that already an (implicit) dependency? A script would formalize that IMO. Have a look at torek's linked answer though.